# Why would esvect produce pixelated arrows?

Tags: miktex, arrows, vector

When using esvect (MiKTeX, pdflatex) I get the following undesirable result:

[image: esvect pixelated arrow]

From this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}
\[\vv{u}\]
\end{document}
```

The arrows are pixelated in SumatraPDF and Adobe Reader, so it's not viewer related.

I suspect it's a font issue, but I am unable to problem solve much further than that.

Comment: No problem. \documentclass{article} \usepackage{esvect} \begin{document} \[\vv{u}\] \end{document} http://i.stack.imgur.com/kjeEF.png

Comment: Can you report whether you see any warnings in your `.log`? Also read the final paragraph under section **1 Installation** of the [`esvect`](http://ctan.org/pkg/esvect) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/esvect/esvect.pdf).

Comment: @WeirdstressFunction Do you have a recently updated MiKTeX? Emphasis on recently.

Comment: @Werner: An installation as described in package documentation should be not necessary, because it could be installed with the package manager of MiKTeX. But in the moment there’s a bug: Upon latest update in November last year the map file was not added to installation file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update:*
The following is now historical. The bug was fixed with MiKTeX update from 2014-04-10, cf. regarding entry in MiKTeX Bug Tracker: [Map file missing for "esvect"](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2315/).

---

There is a very simple reason: MiKTeX installs all of esvect, except `esvect.map`, that is required to use the type 1 versions of the fonts. It actually exists in `esvect-src.tar.bz2`, but the simplest thing to do is to download the map file from [here](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/esvect/dvips/), for instance, and install it in `Your_local_TeXMF\fonts\map\dvips\esvect`.

As MiKTeX  does not create a local TeXMF by default, create one if you haven't done it yet – with all the subdirectories mentioned above.
Then:

1. refresh the FNDB via MiKTeX Settings
2. check if the file "updmap.cfg" in …\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config contains this line: `Map esvect.map`. If it does, jump to step 4.
3. if it doesn't, write the line in your personal updmap.cfg, which should be located in C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config
4. run `updmap` so as the refresh the database of type 1 fonts.

Actually for esvect, you won't have to go through step 3, but I preferred to describe the general procedure. It is also valid for fonts that you would install by yourself.

You will find much more detailed explanations in [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex), to be adapted with the actual path names in your version of Windows (I gave the paths for Windows 7 Pro).

Comment: There are several fonts for which, even if their .map file is installed,  MiKTeX forgot to run updmap. Btw, I've added a detail to my explanation: sometimes there's one more step.

Comment: Maybe one should call to the people to have a list of those fonts that lack something (mainly .map file not installed) in MiKTeX. I'm not sure whether installing a font from the Package Manager, even if the .map files exists includes launching updmap.

Comment: Usually `updmap` is called. I have successfully installed fonts with the Package manager. Much more obscure are BTW these cases where a map exists, but nonetheless no activation is done.

Comment: Just for your information: Bug filed in MiKTEX Bug Tracker: [Map file missing for "esvect"](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2315/).